# PostgreSQL Streaming Replication from 64bit Server to 32bit slave

Tags: windows, postgresql

I need to know if it is possible for Streaming Replication(Postgres) to occur on a Windows system that is 64 bit (Master) to another Windows system that is 32 bit (slave). There are plenty of tutorials on how to get the ball rolling, I'm just curious to know if 64 / 32 infastructure causes problems, Does anyone have any experience in doing this ?

Regards,
Q_Q

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set up streaming (as well as file-based) replication between 64-bit and 32-bit platforms.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/warm-standby.html:

> Hardware need not be exactly the same, but experience shows that
>   maintaining two identical systems is easier than maintaining two
>   dissimilar ones over the lifetime of the application and system. In
>   any case the hardware architecture must be the same — shipping from,
>   say, a 32-bit to a 64-bit system will not work.

This is because 32-bit and 64-bit systems have different representation of data, e. g. fields padding.

But you can set up logical replication instead. There is no standard one yet, but look at [pglogical](http://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/) or [Slony](http://slony.info/), for example.

Comment: What is an alternative solution ?

Comment: As I said, look for logical replication.